# Add a search and filter function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to add a search and filter function.There is a search box in the page. When a user enters a search term in the box, the list of positions is filtered using this search term so that only those jobs with this term in the title are shown.  If multiple words are entered (separated by spaces) then jobs showing either word are shown (ie an implicit OR between search terms).
I have a positions.json file which I have used to generate the latest 10 positions, get the full details of them with a click and add an apply form in it. Now I am not sure how to do the search and filter thing. I am only suppose to use jQuery and handlebar libraries nothing else.

I have this code currently, removed the getJson as I cant seem to incorporate it correctly. If I use it the previous latest 10 list that I generated also go away. Right now stuck here with a broken code in the javascript.

```
var searchField = $(this).val();
if(searchField === '')  {
$('#filter-records').html('');
return;
}

var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
var output = '<div class="row">';
var count = 1;
$.each(data, function(key, val){
if ((val.title.search(regex) != -1) || 
(val.title.search(regex) != -1)) {
output += '<div class== val.title +'" /></div>';
output += '</div>';
$('#filter-records').html(output);
});
```

the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Jobs!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Jobs!</h1>
<div class = "container" style = "width:900px;">
<h2 align ="center"> Search for a Job </h2>
<br /> <br />
<div align = "center">
        <input type = "text" name = "search" placeholder="Search" class = 
    "filter-records" />
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
    <br />
    </div>

<p> Available Jobs</p>

<ul id="jobs">

</ul>
<aside>
<div id="fulldetails">

</div>
</aside>
<!-- load javascript libraries -->
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<!-- load project javascript -->
<!-- note that you can add more modules if you wish -->

<script src="/static/js/model.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Since you havent made any effort to solve it, I am just going to throw this here to get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: I have added it now. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vague overview of how this should work. Can't remember if using Jquery to get file contents is async or not, if it is, this will all have to be nested. The general idea is pretty straight forward, but you'll have to apply some effort (Google / Stack Overflow) to figure out the rest. But having it all laid out in steps should help. Focus on one thing at a time.

use this if you're stuck : https://oscarotero.com/jquery/

It's a cheat sheet for jquery

First off, reading the file from jquery. There's tons of resources on that.

Second step, Again should be pretty straight forward with jquery. Get the search content

Third step is taken care of, the easiest, filter your matching results.

Last step, use handlebars. Will post a link to a handle bars project I did ages ago in the comments

```js
function GenerateSearchHashMap(string searchText)
{
  let hash = {};
  searchText.split(' ').forEach(pos => hash[pos] = true);
  return hash;
}


function FilterMatchingPositions(arraryOfPositions, matchingHash)
{
  return arrayOfPositions.filter(pos => matchingHash[pos]);
}


function ExecuteSearch()
{
  //Use Some J Query to get your positions
  let positions = GetPositionsFromJQuery();
  
  //Get search bar text
  let searchText = GetSearchText();
  
  let searchHash = GenerateSearchHashMap(searchText);
  let results = FilterMatchingPositions(positions, searchHash);
  HandleBarsDoesSomeStuff(results);
}
```

Comment: Applying handle bars in a js file:
https://github.com/ejdelrio/04-html_templating/blob/ed-tim/starter-code/scripts/article.js

Comment: Applying handlebars in html :
https://github.com/ejdelrio/04-html_templating/blob/ed-tim/starter-code/index.html

Comment: Questions that show zero research effort and are expecting a tutorial or free code writing shouldn't be answered. That is not the purpose of SO

Comment: sorry actually I had a broken code so did not bother putting it here. I have 0 idea with this filter thing that is why.